# How to schedule a workflow in AEM?

Tags: workflow, aem

I have to develop a workflow,where admin user has an ability to select date to complete that workflow.

E.g. as soon as workflow notification comes to admin user, he can review the content and select a date so that page can be published.

Is there any OOB functionality available?

Comment: I think `AbsoluteTimeoutHandler` is what you're looking for. This can be used for scheduling the content publishing based on user entered date in the workflow participant step.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this OOTB.

If you have developed a custom workflow, you will have to write code to set a property named `absoluteTime` to the workflows metadata, then make use of OOTB process step called `Absolute Time Auto Advancer` to take it further.

You can also make use of OOTB workflow called `scheduled activation` (`http://<domain>:<port>/etc/workflow/models/scheduled_activation.html`). This might help you achieve your use case completely using OOTB features. This link [here](http://adobeaemclub.com/scheduled-activation-workflows/) will shed more light on how to get this done.

Comment: How to set absoluteTime property to metaData. I have created a dialogue of xtype datetime and using the same dialogue in OOB dialogue participant step to select the date. When I try to set the date nowhere in crx the date is saved.

my dialogue data is:
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <scheduleWorkflo
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Schedule Date"
            name="./abosluteTime"
            xtype="datetime"/>
    </items>